# cy.request with body keys same as value parameter?

Tags: typescript, cypress

Confusing title but I'll keep it simple. Lets say I have a function in cypress that takes multiple values (that will eventually get passed as values in a `cy.request` function.

Lets say the function is something like

```
function createPersonByAPI(
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    phone: string,
)
```

and further down in the function I make a request call:

```
cy.request({
                url: Cypress.env('API_ENDPOINT'),
                method: 'POST',
                body: {
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    phone: phone,
                },
            })
```

So obviously I cannot control the body "keys" that are sent....but the naming convention we have been using for stuff like "First Name" would be `firstName` which is the same as the key.....will this work? Or is there a better way to do this? (Since it looks kinda confusing and I am not even sure if this will work)

This is typescript with Cypress by the way.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? What is the issue? What are you currently trying that is not working?

Comment: @agoff I am asking if it's ok to use a variable for a key that has the same name as the key.

IE: firstName is the key and ALSO the variable for the value of the key

Comment: If they are the same name as the key then you can condense it down to `body: { firstName, lastName, phone}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-using a previously defined variable in a JSONObject is completely fine, and JavaScript is even intelligent enough to interpret only passing in a variable as a key-value pair. [I *believe* this is called shorthand property naming.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions)

```js
const foo = 'bar';

cy.request({ url: '/foo', body: { foo } } );
// is functionally equivalent to...
cy.request({ url: '/foo', body: { foo: foo } } );
```